# IP Header bitwise definition explanation needed

Tags: c, ip, c-preprocessor

In the following code:

```
struct sniff_ip {
    u_char ip_vhl;      /* version << 4 | header length >> 2 */
    u_char ip_tos;      /* type of service */
    u_short ip_len;     /* total length */
    u_short ip_id;      /* identification */
    u_short ip_off;     /* fragment offset field */
#define IP_RF 0x8000        /* reserved fragment flag */
#define IP_DF 0x4000        /* dont fragment flag */
#define IP_MF 0x2000        /* more fragments flag */
#define IP_OFFMASK 0x1fff   /* mask for fragmenting bits */
    u_char ip_ttl;      /* time to live */
    u_char ip_p;        /* protocol */
    u_short ip_sum;     /* checksum */
    struct in_addr ip_src,ip_dst; /* source and dest address */
};
```

How does **C** understand that `IP_RF`, `IP_DF`, `IP_MF`, `IP_OFFMASK` are part of `ip_off`?
And how to access them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`#define`s are a pre-processor command. They are a compile replacement name and are not limited by the scope of that struct.

The author probably put them there to show callers where they should be used.

more reading.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_preprocessor - look at macro definition and expansion.

--or--

http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/preprocessor/

Comment: So you are suggesting that they are only defined here, but the actual assignment of values to each takes place somewhere else?

Comment: @maximilliano #define are replaced by the compiler and are more of a type-less scope-less 'cut-and-paste'. They are not limited by variables you can also define macro functions like `#define MAX(a,b) (a<b)?b:a`